# Volatility spread of Strangle

Tags: volatility, greeks, spread, vega

It's written in a book by Giles Hewitt : " The bid-offer spread quoted on a Strangle in volatility terms will usually be wider than the ATM spread to the same maturity because strikes away from the ATM have less Vega". [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=UxuzCQAAQBAJ&pg=SA8-PA3&lpg=SA8-PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Vega is sensitivity of option price to volatility.  Why should Vega affect the vol spread?

Comment: @alex C Thank you for adding the link.

Comment: I think the paper is implying that if the bid offer of the strangle in premium terms is similar to the ATM, then it will be a wider bid offer in volatility terms.

Comment: Yes, it's a fair deduction. Thanks.